# What's a concise way of sorting and grouping a set in Kotlin?

Tags: sorting, collections, kotlin

From a set of `Comparable` objects I would like to get a sorted list of sets of objects, sorted by their natural order.

This is my solution:

```
  val set: Set<Comparable<A>> = makeThings()
  val sorted = set.sorted()
  val sortedAndGrouped = mutableListOf(mutableSetOf(sorted.first()))
  for(element in sorted.drop(1)) {
     val randomElementOfLastGroup = sortedAndGrouped.last().first()
     val doesNotBelongToLastGroup = randomElementOfLastGroup.compareTo(element) != 0
     if(doesNotBelongToLastGroup)
        sortedAndGrouped.add(mutableSetOf())
     sortedAndGrouped.last().add(element)
  }
```

I would like to know if there is a more concise alternative in Kotlin.

If not, is there one using Java 8 features or a library like Guava?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
fun <A : Comparable<A>> alternativeSortAndGroup(set: Set<A>): List<Set<A>> =
        set.sorted().groupBy { it }.values.map { it.toSet() }
```

Comment: Equals and compareTo need not be always consistent, ie. for two different (!=) objects compareTo could yield 0. And ".groupBy { it }" relies on equality, no? Thanks for the answer but I think this doesn't work. Of course I could also groupBy some value but my comparison could also be an algorithm that can compare two instances but does not necessarily compare them by any concrete calculated value on the object (I think). Even if I use a value, I could change the comparator later and this would be broken, so it seems brittle.

Comment: I would strongly recommend _making_ a concrete calculated value if you don't have one.  This solution is appropriate; you should have objects with equals and hashCode defined that define the grouping.  If you want a custom map type, e.g. a sorted one, you could use `groupByTo` instead.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to sort before grouping, there's no ordering defined for the output of `groupBy`. It works by accident in Kotlin because it uses `LinkedHashMap` which keeps the insertion order. In general I'd consider this a broken approach.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That's a good point, but the documentation states that "The returned map preserves the entry iteration order of the keys produced from the original collection.". So as long as they made it part of the documentation, a developer could rely on it.

Comment: @DPM I didn't realize it was documented :) `groupByTo(sortedMapOf()) { it }` still sounds like a more direct approach.